# Calcium dynamics and its relationship with nitric oxide

Tags: biochemistry

I know that in synaptic transmission nitric oxide release leads to a reduction of calcium inflow. But how does this phenomenon happen quantitatively (for example: I suppose that when the nitric oxide concentration increases, the time derivative of calcium concentration becomes negative and viceversa)? Does a numerical relationship between nitric oxide and calcium concentrations exist, in this sense?